# Scala - Parallel Processing Formulas in an Array

Tags: arrays, scala, parallel-processing

In my code a method gets called repeatedly with slightly different inputs. The method returns a array of objects. Thousands of calculations are done with each of these calls.  I’m wondering if a parallel process could help?

An example method (Scala pseudocode):

```
    def method1(a: int, b: Float, c: Array[objX]): Array[objY] = {
    …
    }
```

For the example I need three variants run through method1:

```
    val result = Array.ofDim[objY](3)
    result(0) = method1(1, 1.1, A)
    result(1) = method1(1, 1.5, A)
    result(2) = method1(2, 1.0, A)
```

On a Single thread this can take unto 3 seconds to process.

Or, would the following be better:

```
    result = Array(
        method1(1, 1.1, A), 
        method1(1, 1.5, A), 
        method1(2, 1.0, A)
    )
```

Or, could I do something like:

```
     result = ParArray(
        method1(1, 1.1, A), 
        method1(1, 1.5, A), 
        method1(2, 1.0, A)
        ).par
```

to enhance the speed of the calculations by working in parallel. Would the above work? Might there be a better alternative?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: If the collection type isn't limited to `Arrays`, I would recommend using immutable collections like `List` and run the methods in `Futures`.

Comment: `Future.traverse(List(a, b, c))(x => Future(method(x)))` something like this.

Answer (score 0):

**Parallel Processing of a Function in Scala**

I’ve managed, after some work, and help from Leo C and Luis Miguel Mejia Suarez, who pointed me in the right direction. I didn’t realize when I asked the question that I needed something that was blocking.

**Blocking** is very important in my situation. The code following the parallel part has to compare results and produce a final answer. So here’s what I’ve done:

My example function just calculates the square of a number:

```
  def method(x: Int): Int = {   // Normal method with out a future
    x * x    // Able to be called with or without future
  }
```

As you can see there is nothing special here.

The calling function uses a yield to process the call to the method in parallel:

```
  def doParallel(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int): Future[List[Int]] = {
    val result1 = Future(method(x))   // the future can be here or in the function
    val result2 = Future(method(y))
    val result3 = Future(method(z))
    val result = for {
      r1 <- result1
      r2 <- result2
      r3 <- result3
    } yield List(r1, r2, r3)
    result
  }
```

Notice the future wrapping each call to method.  This tells the yield that the function should run in parallel.

I just hand back the result at this point. When you call it you have to do the blocking like so:

```
  val rList = new ListBuffer[Int]
  val result = Await.ready(doParallel(1000, 100, 10), Duration.Inf)
  result onComplete {
    case Success(result) => {
      for (rslt <- result)
        rList += rslt
    }
    case Failure(e) => println(s"Failed with ${e.printStackTrace()}")
  }
```

When I call the parallel function I wrap in in a Await call with a Duration.Inf, which means it will wait ‘forever’ if need be before proceeding. If this code, and the onComplete is placed within doParallel function the blocking won’t happen.

With the result created, run it through a onComplete match and if successful get the result out of the list.

That’s it. As you can see you could also call different functions and run them in parallel too here. Very neat and powerful.

Extra note, if you are never going to call your function in a non-parallel manner the Future can go on the called function,  It looks like this:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer


  def method(x: Int): Future[Int] = Future {  // Same as above with future
    x * x
  }

  def doParallel(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int): Future[List[Int]] = {
    val result1 = method(x)  
    val result2 = method(y)
    val result3 = method(z)
    val result = for {
      r1 <- result1
      r2 <- result2
      r3 <- result3
    } yield List(r1, r2, r3)
    result
  }
```

The code must be called correctly, like so:

```
val result = Await.result(doParallel(2, 3, 4), Duration.Inf)
```

Lastly the called libraries are the same in both cases. Done with Scala 2.12.8.